# Need Shorthand Pythonic Answer Of Fizz, Buzz, FizzBuzz Problem

Tags: python, lambda

To clear my concepts of lambda, map & list in python, I am trying to implement [this solution](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fizz-buzz-implementation/) in just one line using lambda instead of passing function "rs" as a param inside map function as shown in the below code.

```py
#Print Fizz, Buzz and FizzBuzz
def rs( n ):
  if ( n % 3 == 0 and n % 5 == 0 ):
    return "FizzBuzz"
  elif ( n % 3 == 0 ):
    return "Fizz"
  elif ( n % 5 == 0 ):
    return "Buzz"
  else:
    return n

print (list( map ( rs , [ i for i in range( 1,100 ) ] ) ) )
```

```
[1, 2, 'Fizz', 4, 'Buzz', 'Fizz', 7, 8, 'Fizz', 'Buzz', 11, 'Fizz', 13, 14, 'FizzBuzz', 16, 17, 'Fizz', 19, 'Buzz', 'Fizz', 22, 23, 'Fizz', 'Buzz', 26, 'Fizz', 28, 29, 'FizzBuzz', 31, 32, 'Fizz', 34, 'Buzz', 'Fizz', 37, 38, 'Fizz', 'Buzz', 41, 'Fizz', 43, 44, 'FizzBuzz', 46, 47, 'Fizz', 49, 'Buzz', 'Fizz', 52, 53, 'Fizz', 'Buzz', 56, 'Fizz', 58, 59, 'FizzBuzz', 61, 62, 'Fizz', 64, 'Buzz', 'Fizz', 67, 68, 'Fizz', 'Buzz', 71, 'Fizz', 73, 74, 'FizzBuzz', 76, 77, 'Fizz', 79, 'Buzz', 'Fizz', 82, 83, 'Fizz', 'Buzz', 86, 'Fizz', 88, 89, 'FizzBuzz', 91, 92, 'Fizz', 94, 'Buzz', 'Fizz', 97, 98, 'Fizz']
```

Any help in this regard is welcome. Best!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need of a lambda function, a list comprehension should be enough.

```
li = ['FizzBuzz' if i%15 == 0 else 'Fizz' if i%3 == 0 else 'Buzz' if i%5 == 0  else i for i in range(1, 100)]
```

The output will be

```
[1, 2, 'Fizz', 4, 'Buzz', 'Fizz', 7, 8, 'Fizz', 'Buzz', 11, 'Fizz', 13, 14,
 'FizzBuzz', 16, 17, 'Fizz', 19, 'Buzz', 'Fizz', 22, 23, 'Fizz', 'Buzz', 26, 
'Fizz', 28, 29, 'FizzBuzz', 31, 32, 'Fizz', 34, 'Buzz', 'Fizz', 37, 38, 
'Fizz', 'Buzz', 41, 'Fizz', 43, 44, 'FizzBuzz', 46, 47, 'Fizz', 49, 'Buzz', 
'Fizz', 52, 53, 'Fizz', 'Buzz', 56, 'Fizz', 58, 59, 'FizzBuzz', 61, 62, 
'Fizz', 64, 'Buzz', 'Fizz', 67, 68, 'Fizz', 'Buzz', 71, 'Fizz', 73, 74, 
'FizzBuzz', 76, 77, 'Fizz', 79, 'Buzz', 'Fizz', 82, 83, 'Fizz', 'Buzz', 86, 
'Fizz', 88, 89, 'FizzBuzz', 91, 92, 'Fizz', 94, 'Buzz', 'Fizz', 97, 98, 
'Fizz']
```

Also the lambda function will be as below and gives the same answer!

```
rs = lambda i: 'FizzBuzz' if i%15 == 0 else 'Fizz' if i%3 == 0 else 'Buzz' if i%5 == 0  else i
print (list( map ( rs , [ i for i in range( 1,100 ) ] ) ) )
```

Or a one-liner

```
print (list( map ( lambda i: 'FizzBuzz' if i%15 == 0 else 'Fizz' if i%3 == 0 else 'Buzz' if i%5 == 0  else i , [ i for i in range( 1,100 ) ] ) ) )
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @devesh. Also, Could you please help me to do in lambda way. I tried with this: 
list( map ( lambda x : "FizzBuzz" if ( n % 3 == 0 and n % 5 == 0 ) else ( "Fizz" if ( n % 3 == 0 ) else ( "Bizz" if ( n % 5 == 0 ) else n  ) for  [ i for i in range( 1,100 ) ] ) )

But this doesn't work

Comment: A lambda would allow to pass `n` and reuse later. Like `lambda n: [ ... range(1, n) ]`

Comment: Have added the lambda function, please check! I have defined lambda function `rs` separately

Answer (score 7):

```py
for x in range(1, 100):
    print(((x % 3 == 0) * 'Fizz' + (x % 5 == 0) * 'Buzz') or x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the **rs** with the **lambda** function like below

```
print (list( map ( lambda n:"FizzBuzz" if n % 3 == 0 and n % 5 == 0 else "Fizz" if n % 3 == 0 else "Buzz" if n % 5 == 0 else n  , [ i for i in range( 1,100 ) ] ) ) )
```